# void* with static_cast vs intptr_t with reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++

I want to know if there are specific, standards-based differences between two different types of casts of very particular types.  In particular, given: type `T` and a variable `T * object` is:

```
intptr_t opaque = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>( object );
T * result = reinterpret_cast<T*>( opaque );
```

equivalent to:

```
void * opaque = static_cast<void*>( object );
T * result = static_cast<T*>( opaque );
```

I only care about the `result`, is it guaranteed to be the same value, equivalent to the original `object` for any type `T`? I don't care what bit pattern the intermediate `opaque` has, as I believe the standard technically allows them to be different in each case (though no sane compiler would have different results).

Note, I'm not interested in the generic case of `static_cast` vs. `reinterpret_cast`, that I understand well. What I'm interested is in the above very specific case -- resulting from the standard assigning special logic to `static_cast` and `void*` that make it behave similar to a `reinterpret_cast`. *(There are several related questions on StackOverflow, but they are more generic, and my scenario I believe is highly specific)*

Style and preference aside, is there any technical reason why one form should be used over the over? Or is it guaranteed, for all `T` to produce the same final `result` variable?

Comment: If `T` is a function type, my guess is that all bets are off in the `static_cast` case.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: in that case, the `static_cast` won't compile.

Comment: @Mike: Right. One rarely casts function pointers to `void*`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, both are guaranteed to restore the original pointer value.

The first is specified by C++11 5.2.10/5:

> A pointer converted
>   to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type
>   will have its original value;

The second is specified by C++11 5.2.9/13:

> A value of type pointer to object
>   converted to “pointer to cv void” and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall have its original
>   value.

There is a technical reason to prefer the second version over the first one: `intptr_t` is optional, but every implementation has `void*`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Yes, you're right (assuming it's `::std::intptr_t`); I had to dig out the C standard to check, since the C++ standard only mentions that it exists.

Comment: From the comments, does a function pointer qualify as a pointer type in both of these snippets?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: for the first, yes; for the second, no - the `static_cast<void*>` is not valid.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y right, and then it defers to the C standard for the description. After the description of `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`, the C standard reads "These types are optional.".

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y - standard C++ makes no provision for casting function pointers to `void*`

Comment: If I read 5.2.10/6 it seems to say you can't use `reinterpret_cast` for function => integral type either. Thus neither form works with function pointers. But wait then 5.2.10/8 says an implementation may support it, and if it does it should work.